# K&R Code for getting an int

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding the code for getting an int in K&R.
Specifically the last line of this function:

```
void getint( int *pn )
{
    int c;
    while (isspace(c = getch()))
        ;

    for (*pn = 0; isdigit(c); c = getch())
        *pn = 10 * *pn + (c - '0') ;
}
```

Comment: The code 1) will store the number at the memory address `pn` points to, 2) initializes the result with 0, 3) reads input from the console as long as digits are entered, 4) converts the entered characters into digits and 5) updates the target number by multiplying the current value with 10 and adding the last digit entered.

Comment: @itharob i was only concerned with one of code. How could i properly format this question

Comment: @Olaf getch() is a function to get chars through a buffer. Its in Section 4.3

Comment: @MilesGaitan: I very well know the book (that's why I discuorage from using it: it only covers a 27 year old outdated version of C which is not standard and includes some nowadays questionable coding styles). (Sidenote: Iff you need to post code in a comment, please use markdown). Still there is no reason to use it instead of `getchar` or `fgetc`.

Comment: The function does not return a value: that would generate a compiler warning. Was it supposed to be the input value, or a status?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what's going on here:

- Since `pn` is a pointer to the result passed by pointer, assigning or reading `*pn` means accessing the result that we have so far. Any change that you make inside this function will be accessible in the context of the caller, who passed you a pointer to `int`.
- Since codes of decimal digits are next to each other, `c-'0'` means a numeric value of the character code representing a digit. For example, if `c` is `'5'` (in single quotes), then `c-'0'` is equal to `5` (no quotes).

Now the rest of the algorithm becomes clear: attaching a digit to the right of a number means taking the prior value of the number, multiplying it by ten, and adding the value of the digit to the result.

For example, if you are reading `"12345"` and you have read `"123"`, then `*pn` is `123`, and the next digit is `4`. You multiply `123` by `10` to get `1230`, and add `4` to it. Now you have `1234`, and the next digit is `5`. You multiply by ten again to get `12340`, and add `5` to get your final result of `12345`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't realize why it was multiplying by 10 but now it makes sense.

Comment: @MilesGaitan You are welcome! When there is no overflow, multiplying by the base of the number system is equivalent to shifting left by one. It works in decimal in the same way as it works in binary (`<<` operator multiplies the number by `2`), and for any number system (hex, octal, base-36 or any other base).

Comment: Why were you confused because of the two `*` operators? One of them is used as a multiplication operator, the other one simply dereferences the pointer, I like it `10 * (*pn)`.

Comment: @itharob i was unclear why there was multiplication by 10. I  didn't know what it was doing.

Comment: @MilesGaitan If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would tell other site visitors that you are no longer actively looking for help with this question, and earn you a brand-new badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Any change that you make inside this method " method, pe you mean Function?

Comment: @Michi Ah, of course! That's what happens when you try answering questions about a mix of C, Swift, Java, C#, and a bunch of other languages: keeping mental track of "methods", "functions", "member variables", "properties", "attributes", and so on becomes a little challenge.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure this is code for inputting an integer faster by reading digits char by char.So this would be something like

```
 void input_int(int *pn)
 {
    for ( *pn = 0; isdigit(c); c =getch())
    *pn = 10 * *pn + ( c - '0') ;
 }
```

and used as

```
 int a;
 input_int(&a);
```

What is happening is that we read the digits char by char and simultaneously create an integer.

Comment: yes the function is getint(int *pn). There is also code in the function for error handling and skipping over white spaces.